# Rails 4: link_to broken in Bootstrap context

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So I am following the Twitter Bootstrap documentation and am trying to implement a simple dropdown `<a>` link with some extra attributes thrown at it in my `.navbar` (cf. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default)

The line in the documentation is:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Which I translated in Rails as :

```
 =link_to who_we_are_path, class:'dropdown-toggle', role:'button', 'aria-expanded' =>'false', data:{toggle: 'dropdown'} do
      Who We Are
      %span.caret
```

Which generates the following HTML:

```
<a aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown=toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/who_we_are" role"button">
"Who We Are"
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </a>
```

Which looks totally valid. However, when I click the text `"Who We Are"` in the DOM, it does not actually go to the `/who_we_are` path, however when I do a mouse hover over the text I see in the bottom left of my browser I see `0.0.0.0:3000/who_we_are`.

Comment: I feel like it may be the fact that I am passing the path as the first argument without using "()", but when I try that I get another syntax error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Because, Role of dropdown is to load Menu Item, Bootstrap prevents Defaults for dropdowns and Shows up a menu. You should add your link inside the Menu or you have to Override Bootstraps defaults.
see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Try this one

```
%div.dropdown
  =link_to "#", class:'dropdown-toggle', role:'button', 'aria-expanded' =>'false', data:{toggle: 'dropdown'} do
      Load Menu
      %span.caret
  %ul.dropdown-menu{role:"menu"}
    %li=link_to "Who We Are", who_we_are_path
```